# compare object-type property inside a collection of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, compare

I have the following $input :

```
elements: array:2 [
    0 => Tournament { 
        id: 1
        amountStaking: Price { 
            value: 2500
            currency: "EUR"
        }
    }
    1 => Tournament { 
        id: 2
        amountStaking: Price { 
            value: 2500
            currency: "EUR"
        }
    }
]
```

What I want to achieve is a function that will return an object or `false` depending of the "equality" of the `$amountStaking` property of each `Tournament`. In the previous input, it should return the "common" Price object :

```
Price { 
    value: 2500
    currency: "EUR"
}
```

But if one of the `$currency` value is "USD" for example, it should return `false`.

Comment: your input array is object type array or normal php array? Also what happen if there  are more than two element  in the input array? Also what you have tried? post it here, so that we can get clear idea.

Comment: my input is a object type array (Doctrine ArrayCollection). If there are more than 2 elements in the input array, it should behave as explain. If all the $amountStaking are equals, it should return the common Price object. it at least one is different, returns false. Right now I didn't write any code. I read about array_column, array_diff and a bunch of other functions, but have no idea how to mix that all together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$last = null;
foreach ($elements as $e) {
  if ($last === null) {
    $last = e->amountStaking;
    continue;
  }
  if ($last->value != $e->value || $last->currence != $e->currency) {
    return false;
  }
  $last = e->amountStaking;
}

return $last;
```

You walk through the array until one entry does not match the previous one. You return false immediately. If it runs through just return the last object.

Maybe you should

```
return clone $last;
```

to make it a new object, in case you want to modify it later.

---

As requested "Price agnostic":

```
$last = null;
foreach ($elements as $e) {
  if ($last === null) {
    $last = e->amountStaking;
    continue;
  }
  foreach ($last as $key => $val) {
    if (!property_exists($e, $key) || $last->$key != $e->$key) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  $last = e->amountStaking;
}

return $last;
```

Comment: any way to make it `Price` agnostic ? I mean if tomorrow I had a property inside Price object, I don't have to update the if() statement to reflect the new property.

Comment: Added a version for that